# Kivy call SELF method from another class

Tags: python, class, methods, kivy, self

In this very simple kivy python program I try to change text label from Window2 class using method in Window1 class.
When I call in Window2 for Window1 method, method is launched, but self.ids .... line is not done.

Any idea what must be changed to make the `self.ids.label1.text = "DONE"` work?

python file

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class ParentWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Window1(BoxLayout):

    def update(self):
        print("This print works, but next line not ...")
        self.ids.label1.text = "DONE"


class Window2(BoxLayout):

    def try_change(self):
        Window1().update()


class MyProgramApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ParentWindow()


MyProgramApp().run()
```

kivy file

```
<ParentWindow>:
    Window1:
    Window2:

<Window1>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: "Try to change me"
    Button:
        text: "Works fine from self class"
        on_press: root.update()

<Window2>:
    Button:
        text: "Lets try"
        on_press: root.try_change()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution:

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class ParentWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Window1(BoxLayout):

    def update(self):
        print("This print work, but next line not ...")
        self.ids.label1.text = "DONE"


class Window2(BoxLayout):

    def try_change(self):
        self.parent.ids.win1.update()


class MyProgramApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ParentWindow()


MyProgramApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<ParentWindow>:
    Window1:
        id: win1
    Window2:


<Window1>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: "Try to change me"
    Button:
        text: "Works fine from self class"
        on_press: root.update()

<Window2>:
    Button:
        text: "Lets try"
        on_press: root.try_change()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a class name followed by `()` in your code, you are creating a new instance of that class. So the `Window1().update()` in the `try_change()` method is creating a new instance of `Window1` (unrelated to the one in your GUI), and calling `update()` on that new instance. That will have no effect on what you see in your GUI.

You need to access the instance of `Window1` that is actually in your GUI. To do that you can change `try_change()` to:

```
def try_change(self):
    # Window1().update()
    window1 = App.get_running_app().root.ids.window1
    window1.update()
```

Along with adding the `window1` id in your `kv`:

```
<ParentWindow>:
    Window1:
        id: window1
    Window2:
```

Comment: Thanks for aswer, but unfortunately it does not work.

window1 = App.get_running_app().root.ids.winndow1
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'